# Calculate invested value from Transcation

Tags: algorithm, calculation

I have a transaction table where a customer buy and sell the units like this

```
Date    Unit    Price/unit    Buy/Sell
01/06   1       100           B
02/06   1       150           B
03/06   4       200           B
04/06   1       150           S
04/06   1       200           S
```

Logically when he sells the unit, he sells at First in First out basis. Technically his left unit is 4 and his current invested value should be `4*200 = 800` because he made a profit on the selling 2 units. Is there a way I can calculate the invested value.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a variable `investing` which loses at buying and gains at buying , like that :

```
int investing = 0 ;
for ( Transaction t : transactions ) {
    if ( (t.buysell).equals("B") ) {
        investing = investing + ( t.price * t.unit ); // making investments
    }
    if ( (t.buysell).equals("S") ) {
        investing = investing - ( t.price * t.unit ); // making profit
    }
}
```